# Scanf function test

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

When `scanf` successfully converts an input character in the requested format, (in this case, a decimal integer `"%d"`), it returns a `1` meaning "conversion successful".

Well, I am afraid I do not get it correctly.

I would like to use this feature to immediately filter the inputs: if the input is not a integer (positive or negative), another input is then requested.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
        int x;
        printf("\nThis function reads an integer\n");
        while(scanf("%d", &x) != 1){
                printf("Please type an integer:\n");
                scanf("%d", &x);
        }
        printf("\n%d is really an integer!\n", x);
        return 0;
}
```

But in this case, with an input of `2.15`, `scanf` reads only the number `2`, and then successfully close the loop.

Comment: Maybe you want to use a floating point format and types? Or you can read the whole line (with e.g.[`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)) and then use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to convert to an integer? With [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) you can check where the conversion ends, and if it converted the whole string or not.

Comment: Why you use 2 times scanf?

Comment: @tilz0R is not the first (scanf("%d", x) == 1) a logic condition?

Comment: Why is there another? First scanf will already put data to your X.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I would directly filter the input not meeting the criteria (being an integer).

Comment: @tilz0R that is really interesting. I thought that only the second would actually read the input.

Comment: the real thing the OP should notice is that if the first call to `scanf()` fails, then the second call will also fail.  This is because when a 'input/conversion' fails, no more of the available characters are input so when the second call to `scanf()` is executed, the same failing character is still in the input stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%d` basically works the same as `strtol`: it discards whitespace, then reads digits until the first non digit character is encountered and converts the read digits to an integer value. If at least one digit has been read, the conversion is deemed successful, no matter what's the character that "stopped the reading".

Thus, in your case `.` is a non digit character, but `2` has already been read, so the conversion uses only the string `"2"` and succeeds.

To solve this you need to first think about what characters you want to be allowed to end an integer (`.` is not among them, obviously). Then read characters until you encounter one of them and convert everything read until then with `strtol`.

Comment: Then, my approach to filter input is not feasible. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

`Scanf` does what you asked it to: it read an integer from input stream and ignored the rest that could not be interpreted as `int`.

If you want to do input filtering, it'd best if you read whole line as a string (for example using `fgets`), parsed the input and acted accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: this is not correct.  The call to `scanf()` did NOT discard the following characters.  Those following characters are still in the input stream, waiting to be processed.

Comment: That was what I meant by "discarded". @user3629249

Comment: Nevertheless I changed the wording to be less confusing. Thanks for the correction @user3629249.